# Is it possible to share appdata files?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

When I try to share an appdata file, it responds with the following error.

> "Method not supported for appdata contents"

Is it possible to share appdata files? I want to implement a feature to share configuration file among application's users. I'm using https://github.com/googledrive/appdatapreferences-android to init a DriveService and using

```
syncer.getDriveService().permissions().insert(permission).execute();
```

to add a new permission but the error above is what I see on the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible, by design - sorry. You have to have a non-appdata regular file for this purpose.

Google are looking at this use-case, so please stay tuned.