# Storing Google Sheets in AppData Folder

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

There is a way to do that?. I'm using [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/appdata) from client browser, even I´ve tryed to convert a csv file into application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet but using v2 the request throws a 403 error saying "Method not supported for appdata contents" and using v3 creates the spreadsheet but in root directory instead of appDataFolder.
And if it isn't possible, can I hide a Google Sheet from the user Drive root?

Here my code to upload (using v3)

```
  const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
  const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";
  var metadata = {
    'title': 'my title ',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet',
    'parents': [{'id': 'appDataFolder'}]
  };
  var multipartRequestBody =
      delimiter +
      'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n' +
      JSON.stringify(metadata) +
      delimiter +
      'Content-Type: text/csv\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      '21/2/2017;prod1;22;33' +
      close_delim;

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'https://content.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&convert=true');
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"');
      xhr.onerror=function(a,b,c){console.log('error',a,b,c)};
      xhr.onload = function(a,b,c){console.log('success',a,b,c)};
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200){
                console.log(xhr.response);
            }
        };
      xhr.send(multipartRequestBody);
```

Comment: I tried to upload CSV file to Google as a spreadsheet. It worked fine. The mimetype I use is text/comma-separated-values for CSV file. And when you want to hide a file on root, you can do it by changing the parent folder information. You can read how to do it here. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update

Comment: @Tenaike Yes, I can convert too, but only if the upload is out of AppData Folder. I just update the question showing my code. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: I have upload a csv file using your metadata and url. It worked file. I confirmed that the csv file was uploaded to a folder with the folder ID and converted to spreadsheet. But my current situation cannot be used your script. So I used curl. I'm sorry. It was found only that CSV file can be uploaded to the folderID using Drive api v3.

Comment: In addition to @Tanaike's comment, this is not currently possible. You have to have a non-appdata regular file for this purpose. You may check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654798/is-it-possible-to-share-appdata-files). And if you want to hide a file from the root, you can change the file's [permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions).

Comment: @abielita Thank you for your support.

Comment: Thank you guys for your messages